# How to add not all data to datagridview?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have data with 40+ items.

I use datagridview to show them.

```
BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
binding.DataSource = MyList;

dataGridView.DataSource = binding;
```

But I need to show only 10 items. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
binding.DataSource = MyList.Take(10).ToList();
```

Comment: @kviki use the [Skip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358985%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method:  `list.Skip(list.Count - 10);`. Or `OrderBy` resp. `OrderByDescending` and then `Take(10)`.

Comment: `binding.DataSource = MyList..Skip(Math.Max(0, MyList.Count() - 10))ToList();` for last items

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
BindingSource binding = new BindingSource();
        binding.DataSource = MyList.Take(10);

        dataGridView.DataSource = binding;
```